# AWS S3 file transfer from a non-AWS Linux server

Tags: amazon-s3

Was wondering if anyone has a solution to transfer files from a non-AWS Linux Server A to a AWS S3 bucket location by using/running commands from a non-AWS Linux Server B?  Is it possible to avoid doing two hops?  Future plan is to automate the process on Server B.

new info:
I am able to upload files to S3 from ServerA such as:
aws s3 sync /path/files s3://bucket/folder
But not sure how to run/execute it from a different Linux server (ServerB)?

Comment: There is nothing special allowing an "AWS Linux" server to talk to S3.  Servers inside AWS talk to S3 in fundamentally the same way as servers outside.  If you are encountering a specific problem trying to communicate with S3 -- from anywhere -- you may need to edit this question to describe the problem more specifically and clearly.

Comment: Have you taken a look at installing the aws-cli tool on server B and authorizing through tokens? You are able to connect to AWS through a non-aws server very easily.

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to using the `aws s3 sync` command from *any* server that supports the aws cli and aws s3 sync command, Linux or otherwise

1. Enable Programmatic Access for the IAM user/account you will use with the AWS CLI and download the credentials

docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html#id_users_create_console

2. Download and install the aws-cli for your operating system

Instructions available for:

- Docker
- Linux
- macOS
- Windows

docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html

3. Configure your aws credentials for your cli

e.g. `aws configure`

docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html

4. Create the bucket you will sync to and allow your aws user/identity access to this bucket

doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/CreatingABucket.html

5. Run the `aws s3 sync` command according to the rules outlined in the official documentation

e.g. `aws s3 sync myfile s3://mybucket`

docs: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#examples